# ASP.NetCore Content Root Path in ConfigureServices() when running as Windows Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, windows-services

When running an Asp.Net Core Application as Windows Service (with the .net Core Compatibility Pack), you have to get the Path of the Applicationdata different than running it normally. As described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x) you have to do this:

```
string pathToContentRoot = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
if (isService) {
    string pathToExe = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
    pathToContentRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToExe);
}
```

and set the Base Path of your Webhostbuilder (shortened):

```
IConfigurationRoot config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                .SetBasePath(pathToContentRoot) 
                                .Build();
IWebHost host = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                       .UseConfiguration(config)
                       .UseStartup<Startup>()
                       .Build();
```

The Problem however is, when you want to access this Path in your Startup.cs in the ConfigureServices(...) Method, i couldn't find a way to do this.

Following things i have tried:

#### #1

Configure Services only takes IServiceCollection, so this is **not allowed**:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IHostingEnvironment env) {...}
```

#### #2

At this Point The HostingEnvironment is not set:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env) {
    HostingEnvironment = env; // <-- is null
}
```

#### #3

Here, the Content Root path is **"C:\Windows\System32"**, and not the one provided in Program.cs

```
string contentRoot = services.BuildServiceProvider()
                             .GetService<IHostingEnvironment>()
                             .ContentRootPath;
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this problem? I also have the same issue.

Comment: @Bravo You can get the path as follows: `Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName` and save it in a static property to be available everywhere.

Comment: Hang on though if your running in .net core you get: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe